# Having trouble getting hang of flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Newbie trying to learn flex. I'm trying to make this responsive across all devices hitting on some just missing on others according to google inspect tool. Followed advise on one post I saw and it got me this far. attached is my html and css. I've tried different combinations of flex x x x but no luck so far looks fine on my laptop screen.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="header">
      <h1>Sci-Fi Blog</h1>
      <h3>dedicated to the Star Trek series</h3>
      <div class="menu">
        <ul>
          <li>About</li>
          <li>Resources</li>
          <li>Other Sci-Fi series</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </div>    
    
      
  <div class="container1">
      <div class="row1">
        <div class="STtos">
          <h2>Star Trek TOS</h2>
          <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSTPdHkIFqZgTABvQtjcCnKr6mbWNfKBVDRRw&usqp=CAU" alt = "Pic of space ship">
          <p>Turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna. Tristique risus nec feugiat in fermentum posuere urna. In nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a. Venenatis urna cursus eget nunc scelerisque viverra mauris in aliquam. Sed pulvinar proin gravida hendrerit lectus a. In dictum non consectetur a erat nam. </p><a href="#"> <button>Read More</button></a>  <a href="#"><button>Comment</button></a>
          
        </div> <!--div STtos-->
        
        <div class="STTNG">
          <h2>Star Trek TNG</h2>
          <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQueIPqKDTgGH9_SaYzT7u9cfpvKs2P48l5dg&usqp=CAU" alt="pic of space ship">
          <p>Mauris ultrices eros in cursus. At imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi. Pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras. Sem integer vitae justo eget magna fermentum iaculis eu non. Faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper. Convallis aenean et tortor at risus viverra adipiscing at in. Fermentum dui faucibus in ornare quam viverra orci. Sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum integer. </p><a href="#"><button>Read More</button></a>  <a href="#"><button>Comment</button></a>

        </div> <!--end of STTNG-->
        
        <div class="DS9">
          
          <h2>Deep Space Nine</h2>
          <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRKvwoJTvGIl2Nq2RzDKkf7OrgfVoHwrXP82A&usqp=CAU" alt="pic">
          <p>Mauris ultrices eros in cursus. At imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi. Pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras. Sem integer vitae justo eget magna fermentum iaculis eu non. Faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper. Convallis aenean et tortor at risus viverra adipiscing at in. Fermentum dui faucibus in ornare quam viverra orci. Sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum integer. </p><a href="#"><button>Read More</button></a> <a href="#"><button>Comment</button></a>
          
        </div> <!--DS9 -->
        
      </div> <!--row1 -->
  </div> <!--container1-->

  <div class="container2">
      <div class="row2">
          <div class="StarTrekTAS">
          <h2>Star Trek TAS</h2>
          <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQwdlJfrFrcj7KJRdTADDtsfjGa0SQweeu0fQ&usqp=CAU" width="259" height="194" alt="pic">
          <p>Mauris ultrices eros in cursus. At imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi. Pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras. Sem integer vitae justo eget magna fermentum iaculis eu non. Faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper. Convallis aenean et tortor at risus viverra adipiscing at in. Fermentum dui faucibus in ornare quam viverra orci. Sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum integer. </p><a href="#"><button>Read More</button></a> <a href="#"><button>Comment</button></a>
                    
          </div> <!--end of TAS-->

          <div class="voyager">
          <h2>Voyager</h2>
          <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRiV6QTXDR7lD9uvx8S-IuTClS-CV6COgSh1g&usqp=CAU" width="259" height="194" alt="pic">
          <p>Mauris ultrices eros in cursus. At imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi. Pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras. Sem integer vitae justo eget magna fermentum iaculis eu non. Faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper. Convallis aenean et tortor at risus viverra adipiscing at in. Fermentum dui faucibus in ornare quam viverra orci. Sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum integer. </p><a href="#"><button>Read More</button></a>  <a href="#"><button>Comment</button></a>
    
          </div> <!--end of Voyager-->
        <div class="Enterprise">
          <h2>Enterprise</h2>
          <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTa4Iz2D0_InBOZg4Wi_PWAT-1lEqxI0AExPg&usqp=CAU" width="259" height="194" alt="pic">
          <p>Turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna. Tristique risus nec feugiat in fermentum posuere urna. In nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a. Venenatis urna cursus eget nunc scelerisque viverra mauris in aliquam. Sed pulvinar proin gravida hendrerit lectus a. In dictum non consectetur a erat nam. </p><a href="#"><button>Read More</button></a>  <a href="#"><button>Comment</button></a>
          </div>
      </div> <!--end of row2-->


      </div> <!--end of container2-->


    
  </body>
  </html>

    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding:0;
      box-sizing:border-box;
    }


    .header {
      background: url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQSzBDemswC2Gg3mbDR7t8mQ53jByPChDtA5w&usqp=CAU');

    text-align:center;
    background-size:no repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    height:310px;
    color:white;
    margin-bottom: 150px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right:5px;

    }

    .header h1 {
      margin:0;
    }

    li {
      list-style-type:none;
      display:inline-block;
      padding: 10px;
    }

    .menu ul {
      text-align:center;
      display:inline-block;
      padding: 0px;
      background: rgba(197, 228, 183, 0.8);
      
      
    }

    .menu {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-left: 10px;
      
    }


    p a {
      display:inline;
    }







    @media screen and (min-width:640px) {

      

      
      .row1 {
        display:flex;
        justify-content:space-evenly;
        grid-gap:10px;
        
        
            
      }

      .STtos {
        flex: 0;
      }

      .STTNG {
        flex:0;
      }

      .DS9 {
        flex:0;
      }

      .row2 {
        display:flex;
        justify-content:space-evenly;
        grid-gap:10px;
        
            
      }

      .StarTrekTAS {
        flex: 0 0;
      }

      .voyager {
        flex:0 0;
      }

      .Enterprise {
        flex:0 0;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

We often talk about something being responsive as if it is a binary condition (as if it is or it isn't), but really there are tons of ways your site could adapt itself to different screenresolutions or classes of devices.

Currently, if we ignore your header/menu (which seem unrelated to the issue), your site contains 6 chunks of similar types of content. You've wrapped those into in 2 `.row`s containing 3 each, i suspect this is a mistake (more on that later) but it makes sense if you look at the site through the lens of your laptop browser.

When the site is displayed with all 3 items side by side, it looks great on fullsize desktops (which includes your laptop i guess), because the `@media { ... }` block in your CSS, is in effect. The styles inside that block enable flexbox and make it look probably more or less like you had in mind.
When you shrink the site down though, beyond the cut-off point of your (only) `@media { ... }` block, all the styles in that block are de-activated, and the browser falls back to rendering them as-if you had no CSS at all. Now, that default style isn't actually -too- bad for say a phone, but it's not what most designers (including you) are likely to want.

The likely desired result (i suspect) is that your site looks more or less like it does on desktop right now (2 rows of 3 columns), but once the screen gets smaller it should responsively turn into a 2-column and finally 1-column layout.

The main problem lies in the CSS, instead of having all your styles inside the one `@media { ... }` block and flicking that on/off like a light switch, you want most of your styles to be generic and then have a minimal amount of *specific styles* inside `@media { ... }` blocks for the different situations.

Let's remove most problems first, then re-create them; let's **delete the following line, and everything under there** in your CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width:640px) {
```

Next, we'll look at the HTML. While not strictly wrong perse; the 4 names `container1`, `container2`, `row1` and `row2` aren't very useful as `class`names. `id`s are for **uniquely** naming things, classes are for labeling stuff that is similar to other stuff. The later case is what matters to us at this moment.

Lets change both container classes to just `container` and the 2 rows to just `row` (eg: remove the numbers).
Next, the 6 startrek `<div>`s all have unique classnames (like `class="STtos"`) change those 6 to being `id`s (like `id="STtos"`) and also assign all 6 `<div>`s a shared class `class="contentitem"` (so now they'll look like: `<div id="STtos" class="contentitem">`).

Now, there is *one* more problem in the HTML, but we'll get back to that later, let us re-create some CSS now.

We want the `.row`s to be flexboxes (which contain the `.contentitem`s):

```
.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
```

And then the 6 `.contentitem`s themselves, for simplicity for now, let's define each as needing 200 pixels of width, not allow them to grow when there is plenty of room (first `0`) nor allow them to shrink if there is little room (second `0`):

```
.contentitem {
    flex: 0 0 200px;
}
```

Now test it out on your laptop, that should be pretty much identical to before with 3 columns.
Now shrink the screen too a very low width -> it'll `wrap` to only 1 column.
Now scale back up a little so it `wrap`s to 2 columns.

Here, you'll see the effect of the last problem i ignored before. You've wrapped your content into 2 `.row`s because you had 3 items side by side in mind while creating it.
There was no reason to have multiple `.row`s in this case at all.

In the HTML source, just above `<div class="contentitem" id="StarTrekTAS">`, lets remove these 4 lines:

```
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
```

Now your content adapts the screen size fully dynamically, if the screen is wide enough you can even get all 6 side by side (or 5, or 4, or ...). Also without the manual `.row`splitting, when you shrink down to the right width for 2 columns side-by-side, it will really be 3 rows of 2, instead of 4 rows where 2 of them are half-empty.

---

The entire thing after all these changes (and with the CSS moved into `<style>` for myself):

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            /* untouched css */
            body {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            .header {
                background: url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQSzBDemswC2Gg3mbDR7t8mQ53jByPChDtA5w&usqp=CAU');
                text-align: center;
                background-size: no repeat;
                background-size: cover;
                height: 310px;
                color: white;
                margin-bottom: 150px;
                margin-left: 5px;
                margin-right: 5px;
            }
            .header h1 {
                margin: 0;
            }
            li {
                list-style-type: none;
                display: inline-block;
                padding: 10px;
            }
            .menu ul {
                text-align: center;
                display: inline-block;
                padding: 0px;
                background: rgba(197, 228, 183, 0.8);


            }
            .menu {
                display: inline-block;
                margin-left: 10px;

            }
            p a {
                display: inline;
            }
            /* the css under here is changed */

            .row {
                display: flex;
                flex-flow: row wrap;
                justify-content: space-evenly;
            }
            .contentitem {
                flex: 0 0 200px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <h1>Sci-Fi Blog</h1>
            <h3>dedicated to the Star Trek series</h3>
            <div class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li>About</li>
                    <li>Resources</li>
                    <li>Other Sci-Fi series</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="contentitem" id="STtos">
                    <h2>Star Trek TOS</h2>
                    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSTPdHkIFqZgTABvQtjcCnKr6mbWNfKBVDRRw&usqp=CAU"
                        alt="Pic of space ship">
                    <p>Turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna. Tristique risus nec feugiat in fermentum posuere urna.
                        In nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a. Venenatis urna cursus eget nunc scelerisque viverra mauris
                        in aliquam. Sed pulvinar proin gravida hendrerit lectus a. In dictum non consectetur a erat nam.
                    </p>
                    <a href="#"> <button>Read More</button></a>
                    <a href="#"><button>Comment</button></a>
                </div>
                <!--div STtos-->

                <div class="contentitem" id="STTNG">
                    <h2>Star Trek TNG</h2>
                    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQueIPqKDTgGH9_SaYzT7u9cfpvKs2P48l5dg&usqp=CAU"
                        alt="pic of space ship">
                    <p>Mauris ultrices eros in cursus. At imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi. Pellentesque eu
                        tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras. Sem integer vitae justo eget magna fermentum iaculis
                        eu non. Faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper. Convallis aenean et tortor at risus viverra
                        adipiscing at in. Fermentum dui faucibus in ornare quam viverra orci. Sagittis id consectetur purus
                        ut faucibus pulvinar elementum integer. </p>
                    <a href="#"><button>Read More</button></a>
                    <a href="#"><button>Comment</button></a>
                </div>
                <!--end of STTNG-->

                <div class="contentitem" id="DS9">
                    <h2>Deep Space Nine</h2>
                    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRKvwoJTvGIl2Nq2RzDKkf7OrgfVoHwrXP82A&usqp=CAU"
                        alt="pic">
                    <p>Mauris ultrices eros in cursus. At imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi. Pellentesque eu
                        tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras. Sem integer vitae justo eget magna fermentum iaculis
                        eu non. Faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper. Convallis aenean et tortor at risus viverra
                        adipiscing at in. Fermentum dui faucibus in ornare quam viverra orci. Sagittis id consectetur purus
                        ut faucibus pulvinar elementum integer. </p>
                    <a href="#"><button>Read More</button></a>
                    <a href="#"><button>Comment</button></a>
                </div>
                <!--DS9 -->

                <div class="contentitem" id="StarTrekTAS">
                    <h2>Star Trek TAS</h2>
                    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQwdlJfrFrcj7KJRdTADDtsfjGa0SQweeu0fQ&usqp=CAU"
                        width="259" height="194" alt="pic">
                    <p>Mauris ultrices eros in cursus. At imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi. Pellentesque eu
                        tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras. Sem integer vitae justo eget magna fermentum iaculis
                        eu non. Faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper. Convallis aenean et tortor at risus viverra
                        adipiscing at in. Fermentum dui faucibus in ornare quam viverra orci. Sagittis id consectetur purus
                        ut faucibus pulvinar elementum integer. </p>
                    <a href="#"><button>Read More</button></a>
                    <a href="#"><button>Comment</button></a>
                </div>
                <!--end of TAS-->

                <div class="contentitem" id="voyager">
                    <h2>Voyager</h2>
                    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRiV6QTXDR7lD9uvx8S-IuTClS-CV6COgSh1g&usqp=CAU"
                        width="259" height="194" alt="pic">
                    <p>Mauris ultrices eros in cursus. At imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi. Pellentesque eu
                        tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras. Sem integer vitae justo eget magna fermentum iaculis
                        eu non. Faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper. Convallis aenean et tortor at risus viverra
                        adipiscing at in. Fermentum dui faucibus in ornare quam viverra orci. Sagittis id consectetur purus
                        ut faucibus pulvinar elementum integer. </p>
                    <a href="#"><button>Read More</button></a>
                    <a href="#"><button>Comment</button></a>
                </div>
                <!--end of Voyager-->

                <div class="contentitem" id="Enterprise">
                    <h2>Enterprise</h2>
                    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTa4Iz2D0_InBOZg4Wi_PWAT-1lEqxI0AExPg&usqp=CAU"
                        width="259" height="194" alt="pic">
                    <p>Turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra magna. Tristique risus nec feugiat in fermentum posuere urna.
                        In nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a. Venenatis urna cursus eget nunc scelerisque viverra mauris
                        in aliquam. Sed pulvinar proin gravida hendrerit lectus a. In dictum non consectetur a erat nam.
                    </p>
                    <a href="#"><button>Read More</button></a>
                    <a href="#"><button>Comment</button></a>
                </div>
                <!--end of Enterprise-->

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

Now, if you actually wanted to bring media queries back in, to make some other more explicit changes between the different resolutions, then you could (for example) add this to your CSS, **below** all your other styles:

```
        @media screen {
            /* (S) what you write in here, applies to any resolution (Small, Medium and Large) */
        }
        @media screen and (min-width:590px) {
            /* (M) what you write in here, only applies to 590px or wider (Medium and Large screens) */
        }
        @media screen and (min-width:1000px) { 
            /* (L) applies to 1000px or wider (Large screens only) */
        }
```

There are 2 things to note here:

1. I have basically chosen to recognize 3 different screen sizes (small/medium/large) with the cut-off points between them being 590px and 1000px (which are just arbitrary example numbers).
2. The 3 different `@media` blocks are **not** specific to small/medium/large, each affects its *bigger* variants as well. So the 3 `@media` blocks should perhaps be labeled as the *SML*, *ML* and *L* blocks.

If you wanted to change some background-color to yellow only for the smallest (*S*) screens, then you'd:

- Put `background-color: yellow;` in the *S* block
- Put `background-color: white;` in the *M* block, to prevent *M* and *L* size screens from being affected by the yellow.

Or perhaps more specific to your site, if you wanted to never show more than 3 contentitems side by side, you could add this to the Large (*L*) block:

```
            .contentitem {
                flex-basis: 30%;
            }
```

That would override the `200px` we defined earlier on (in the `flex` property) with `30%`.

Comment: Very, very thorough and impressive.

Comment: actually you changes do not make the page the way I intended. instead of 2 rows I now have one row and is not responsive. I even copied/pasted updated code but still only see one row not two.

Comment: It being 1 row was intentional (on my part); By not responsive do you mean it remains as 1 row even when you shrink down your browser screen ? because that should not be the case. Responsiveness (in this context) generally implies that something dynamically deals with change (or with different scenarios). In this particular example that means instead of defining some exact amount of columns, we use a responsive layout which tailors itself to the available space. That could mean 1-column on a tiny phone or even 40-columns, if someone uses a screen/browser wide enough for that.

Comment: If you instead want to micro-manage such effects, you can use those media queries at the end of my answer to do so; but that is the act of making the site **less** responsive.

Comment: You'll also have to think about how you'd want the endresult to look, there are many easy ways of enforcing a 3-column layout, but does that mean you want all the "extra room" to be used for padding inbetween or around the 3 items ? or do you want the items themselves to become much wider, or ... ; you get the idea.  Also, its kind of out-of-scope since you did ask this specificly as a flexbox-question, but `grid` is likely more tailored to your actual desire than flexbox in this case (they're very similar).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your divs responsive i.e. in row direction when on pc and in column on mobile. You first have to define `display: flex` to the parent div so that all the divs inside it will be arrange in row sequence and inside the `@media` query just add one more property `flex-direction: column` this will change the default value of `flex-direction` which is `row` to `column`.

[This link from w3schools might help](https://www.w3schools.com/css//css3_flexbox_container.asp#flex-direction)